# Problem saving time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have an application which save datetime using Time.now, but when I retrieves it and compare with Time.now again it not the same format and result in unexpected result.

What should I do to always make this time standard all the time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails treats time in a special way because time zone support in Ruby was deemed insufficient, i.e. Ruby Time instances only work with UTC and `ENV['TZ']` A Time object persisted in ActiveRecord will therefore look quite different to the return value of `Time.now`. To get on the same page as Rails use `Time.zone.now`

Answer (score 0):

Favorite thing ever when it comes to time parsing and standardizing values is the [Chronic](http://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem. Natural format time parser. Very handy. Saves me from a lot of work trying to write/read time formats correctly for databasing time formats. Maybe not really the solution to the problem, but its worth a look.